# Problem validating a date input to be over 18 years

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date input field in a form which fetches date of birth from user,, I have created backend validation which checks that the **date of birth entered by the user is above 18 years**,, need to implement this on the frontend using some Javascript or Jquery which I have no idea how to handle it..

**Input field containing date of birth**

```
<div class="form-line registar love {{ $errors->has('dob') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <input type="date" class="form-input" name="dob" value="{{ old('dob') }}" required>
      <label>Date of Birth *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
      @if ($errors->has('dob'))
            <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('dob') }}</strong>
            </span>
      @endif
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    function validateForm(event) {
        // Store value of date of birth field
        let dateOfBirthFieldValue = document.getElementById("dob").value;
        let bday = new Date(dateOfBirthFieldValue);
        let todayDate = new Date();
        let timeDiff = Math.abs(todayDate.getTime() - bday.getTime());
        let diffyears = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)/365); 
        return diffyears > 18; // or you can change value according to your requirement
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot,, what If I want to generate some custom error messages to display to the user.

Comment: let isValid = diffyears > 18; 
            if( !isValid ){
               document.getElementById("dobError").innerHTML = " --- error message -- ";
            }
            return isValid;

Comment: This is an approximation at best. Given `new Date(dateOfBirthFieldValue)` returns a date in YYYY-MM-DD format, the date will be treated as UTC, not local. Also, there are more than 365 days in some years and not all days are 24 hours long.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the onSubmit event listener to first listen for the form being submitted:

```
document.getElementById("my-form").addEventListener('submit', validateForm);

function validateForm(event) {
    // Store value of date of birth field
    let dateOfBirthFieldValue = document.getElementById("dob").value;

    // Boolean to store the status of the validation
    let isValid = false;

    // some validation logic (as per backend), set isValid to true if dob is valid

    // if isValid is false, the form will not submit
    return isValid; 
}
```

You could also add some logic in to the function to update the respective form label to include information regarding the error. Should be quite simple with jQuery. Here is some [further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation).

Comment: Okay duly noted,,, What i want is some some logic to check if the date chosen is over 18 years from the current date,, if ture throw an error to the user eg you must be over 18 years old

Comment: Ah apologies. I wasn't sure if you required the logic or help with handling the submission.